# How to upload android react-native app to hockeyapp

Tags: android, react-native, hockeyapp

How do I build the react-native app so I can test it in hockeyapp without being connected?

I'm using react-native-hockeyapp and successfully built the app, which listed it on hockeyapp, but now with the hockeyapp changes:

1. It does not run on a connected device with `run-android` and I get a white screen and no console debug messages anymore.
2. When I uploaded the app_Debug.apk to the hockeyapp by dragging it on the website, I got an invite. Run it on my device and get the white screen and the following two errors:

   a. unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. Make sure your bundle is pakcaged correctly...
   It then shows a white screen.

   b. If I shake and press reload it says: could not connect ot development server. I don't want to connect to development server. I want to test it disconnected!

   1. How do I build the app?  In Android Studio?  Any pointer to instructions?
   2. And how do I preserve the possibility to `react-native run-android` so that I can test it locally and debug quickly for development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a keystore and then went to `myproject/android` folder and `gradlew assembleRelease`

See https://github.com/benloopcompany/react-native-hockeyapp/issues/84 for more details